# Partition failed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, partition

Trying to shrink my default full disk partition to create some free space (for Ubuntu, incidentally, which I'm longing for even more now).

```
Partition failed
Partition failed with the error:

Couldn't modify partition map because file system verification failed
```

I've tried the advice here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/05/fix-partition-failed-error-mac/

Including booting to single user mode to run /sbin/fsck -fy and booting from the recovery partition to run disk utility to repair the disk and try partitioning there.

Verify disk seems to think everything's ok but I'm still at a loss as to how I can shrink the partition to create some free space.

Answer (score 1):

Try [booting from a USB drive](http://www.tonymacx86.com/374-unibeast-install-os-x-mavericks-any-supported-intel-based-pc.html) and running Disk Utility from there on your drive, using [this method](http://osxdaily.com/2009/11/20/resize-partitions-in-mac-os-x-with-disk-utility/) in Disk Utility. You can just slide to resize the partition.

[image: You can drag and drop]

Comment: after to resize, how do you actually **format** the empty space?